# How do I program a TreeView in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, nodes

I have a tree view in my asp.net page, but I don't know how to program another childnodes. In my treeview I want to show data from my table "MyTable". My table is divided into id, name and level, but in the first node I want to show the first level, in the childnode I want to show the rows they are in second level and as another childnode I want to show the third level in "MyTable". I tried to do that with the following code:

```
Dim SqlCommand As String = String.Empty
    Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    SqlString = "select name, id from MyTable"
       Try
        MsDb = New Clase_Coneccion
        Dim Dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = MsDb.ConsultaDB(SqlString, MsDb.MsSqlServer)
        While (Dr.Read())
            Dim Nodo As New TreeNode
            Nodo.Text = Dr("name").ToString()
            Nodo.Value = Dr("id").ToString()
            Nodo.PopulateOnDemand = (CInt(Dr("id")) > 0)
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Nodo)
       End While
       Return
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

That's how I get the first nodes with all the names from "MyTable", but I don't know how to specify the childnodes for 2nd and 3d level. Any idea?